why add to cart button suddenly dissapeard
i have this website https://biossaf-dz.org/ ,
it's using organic astra theme , it contains the add to cart button by default , i was trying to add the buy now button under the add to cart button , now the add to cart is not showing at all , what could be causing the problem?
i tried adding it using some code to show it again , but it did nothing ,  and after disabeling the WPC buy now button plugin even the buy now button dissapeard,how can i show the add to cart button + the buy now in the home page

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

question edited
